# Techniques for logging into websites programmatically

Tags: c#, browser, login-automation

I am trying to automate logging into Photobucket for API use for a project that requires automated photo downloading using stored credentials.

The API generates a URL to use for logging in, and using Firebug i can see what requests and responses are being sent/received.

My question is, how can i use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to mimic what happens in the browser in C#?

Would it be possible to use a web browser component inside a C# app, populate the username and password fields and submit the login?

Comment: Are you using the Photobucket API (http://photobucket.com/developer/documentation)?

Comment: yes i am using the PhotobucketNet API from here: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/btIie8iQer3zs-ab7jnrAJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this kind of thing before, and ended up with a nice toolkit for writing these types of applications.  I've used this toolkit to handle non-trivial back-n-forth web requests, so it's entirely possible, and not extremely difficult.

I found out quickly that doing the `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` from scratch really was lower-level than I wanted to be dealing with.  My tools are based entirely around the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) by Simon Mourier.  It's an excellent toolset. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, and makes parsing of the fetched HTML *really* easy.  If you can rock XPath queries, the HtmlAgilityPack is where you want to start. It handles poorly foormed HTML quite well too!

You still need a good tool to help debug.  Besides what you have in your debugger, being able to inspect the http/https traffic as it goes back-n-forth across the wire is priceless.  Since you're code is going to be making these requests, not your browser, FireBug isn't going to be of much help debugging your code.  There's all sorts of packet sniffer tools, but for HTTP/HTTPS debugging, I don't think you can beat the ease of use and power of [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  The newest version even comes with a plugin for firefox to quickly divert requests through fiddler and back. Because it can also act as a seamless HTTPS proxy you can inspect your HTTPS traffic as well.

Give 'em a try, I'm sure they'll be two indispensable tools in your hacking.

**Update:** Added the below code example.  This is pulled from a not-much-larger "Session" class that logs into a website and keeps a hold of the related cookies for you.  I choose this because it does more than a simple 'please fetch that web page for me' code, plus it has a line-or-two of XPath querying against the final destination page.

```
public bool Connect() {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Username)) { base.ThrowHelper(new SessionException("Username not specified.")); } 
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Password)) { base.ThrowHelper(new SessionException("Password not specified.")); }

   _Cookies = new CookieContainer();
   HtmlWeb webFetcher = new HtmlWeb();
   webFetcher.UsingCache = false;
   webFetcher.UseCookies = true;

   HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler justSetCookies = delegate(HttpWebRequest webRequest) {
      SetRequestHeaders(webRequest, false);
      return true;
   };
   HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler postLoginInformation = delegate(HttpWebRequest webRequest) {
      SetRequestHeaders(webRequest, false);

      // before we let webGrabber get the response from the server, we must POST the login form's data
      // This posted form data is *VERY* specific to the web site in question, and it must be exactly right,
      // and exactly what the remote server is expecting, otherwise it will not work!
      //
      // You need to use an HTTP proxy/debugger such as Fiddler in order to adequately inspect the 
      // posted form data. 
      ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
      string postDataString = string.Format("edit%5Bname%5D={0}&edit%5Bpass%5D={1}&edit%5Bform_id%5D=user_login&op=Log+in", _Username, _Password);
      byte[] postData = encoding.GetBytes(postDataString);
      webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;
      webRequest.Referer = Util.MakeUrlCore("/user"); // builds a proper-for-this-website referer string

      using (Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
         postStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
         postStream.Close();
      }

      return true;
   };

   string loginUrl = Util.GetUrlCore(ProjectUrl.Login); 
   bool atEndOfRedirects = false;
   string method = "POST";
   webFetcher.PreRequest = postLoginInformation;

   // this is trimmed...this was trimmed in order to handle one of those 'interesting' 
   // login processes...
   webFetcher.PostResponse = delegate(HttpWebRequest webRequest, HttpWebResponse response) {
      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found) {
         // the login process is forwarding us on...update the URL to move to...
         loginUrl = response.Headers["Location"] as String;
         method = "GET";
         webFetcher.PreRequest = justSetCookies; // we only need to post cookies now, not all the login info
      } else {
         atEndOfRedirects = true;
      }

      foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies) {
         // *snip*
      }
   };

   // Real work starts here:
   HtmlDocument retrievedDocument = null;
   while (!atEndOfRedirects) {
      retrievedDocument = webFetcher.Load(loginUrl, method);
   }


   // ok, we're fully logged in.  Check the returned HTML to see if we're sitting at an error page, or
   // if we're successfully logged in.
   if (retrievedDocument != null) {
      HtmlNode errorNode = retrievedDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'error')]");
      if (errorNode != null) { return false; }
   }

   return true; 
}


public void SetRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest webRequest) { SetRequestHeaders(webRequest, true); }
public void SetRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest webRequest, bool allowAutoRedirect) {
   try {
      webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = allowAutoRedirect;
      webRequest.CookieContainer = _Cookies;

      // the rest of this stuff is just to try and make our request *look* like FireFox. 
      webRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3";
      webRequest.Accept = @"text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
      webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
      webRequest.Headers.Add(@"Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
      //webRequest.Headers.Add(@"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { base.ThrowHelper(ex); }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I should add that I've used Fiddler and the HtmlAgilityPack to get logged into some web sites which do some 'tricky' crap in the login process.

Comment: Firebug also contains Http traffic monitoring so you can see what is being sent and received.

Comment: I found that the WebBrowserControl solution i came up with will suite my needs pretty well. I already wired up launching the forms app from a command line app, capturing the console output of the forms app (in the forms app i do a Console.WriteLine with the auth token) so that i can pass that into the rest of the system. Thanks for your response though, i will keep the HtmlAgilityPack in mind for the future.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a simple solution.  After having used the HtmlAgilityPack for a while now, it's my go-to solution for this type of work, but like anything new, there's a small learning curve. 

I've used the HtmlAgilityPack for what I'm assuming is the same type of auth-token you're talking about.  I've used it to interact with Drupal CMS which has per-session/per-form tokens...

Comment: Do you have any examples of how i can use HtmlAgilityPack to interact with the website like you did? i tried searching around but i couldnt come up with anything.

Comment: Updated with a sizable, yet incomplete, example... You should be able to get a feel for it though.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i solved it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private string LoginUrl = "/apilogin/login";
        private string authorizeUrl = "/apilogin/authorize";
        private string doneUrl = "/apilogin/done";

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            PhotobucketNet.Photobucket pb = new Photobucket("pubkey","privatekey");
            string url = pb.GenerateUserLoginUrl();
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(url);
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(LoginUrl))
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usernameemail").SetAttribute("Value","some username");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value","some password");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("click");
            }

            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(authorizeUrl))
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("allow").InvokeMember("click");
            }

            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(doneUrl))
            {
                string token = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("oauth_token").GetAttribute("value");
            }
        }
    }
```

the token capture in the last if block is what is needed to continue using the API. This method works fine for me as of course the code that needs this will be running on windows so i have no problem spawning a process to load this separate app to extract the token.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the native WebbrowserControl to login into websites. But as u see in the example u'll have to identify the name of the control before.

```
private void webBrowserLogin_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (webBrowserLogin.Url.ToString() == WebSiteUrl)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowserLogin.Document.All)
            {

                if (elem.Name == "user_name")              // name of the username input
                {
                    elem.InnerText = UserName;               
                }

                if (elem.Name == "password")               // name of the password input
                {
                    elem.InnerText = Password;                
                } 

            }

            foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowserLogin.Document.All)
            {

                if (elem.GetAttribute("value") == "Login")
                {
                    elem.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the method i went with, but i used a more direct approach to get the elements i was interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Rohit's BrowserSession class which he's described [here](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.de/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html) (and [part 2 here](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post_19.html)). Based on HtmlAgilityPack but does some of the boring work of populating POST data from a FORM.